# I need to convert to codeigniter3 active record syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter-3

I need to join main (4-5) tables and get the latest from the inner join table to get the project current status.

> investor have many investments
>
> investments have many investment_details
>
> investment_details has many status through project status

```
Select 
    siv.company_name
    , siv.full_name
    , si.permit_number
    , si.project_name
    , sid.investment_detailed_id
    , sis.project_status_id
    , sps.project_status_name 
    From sma_investors siv 
        Join sma_investments si 
            On siv.investor_id = si.investment_id 
        Join sma_investment_details sid 
            On si.investment_id = sid.investment_id 
        Inner Join sma_investment_status sis 
            On sis.investment_status_id = (
                Select investment_status_id 
                From sma_investment_status s 
                Where s.investment_detailed_id = sid.investment_detailed_id 
                Order BY investment_status_id DESC LIMIT 1) 
        Join sma_project_status sps 
            On sis.project_status_id = sps.project_status_id
```

This works fine but I can't convert it the CI3.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server, other than "that's where the code was initially written"?  What specific issue(s) do you have converting it to Code Igniter?

Comment: Yes I want to convert it to codeigniter3 query builder

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what were the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally come up with my own solution and stick to the QB codding standard and  it works as i expected

```
 $q = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('investors')
            ->join('investments', `enter code here`'investors.investor_id=investments.investment_id')
            ->join('investment_details as sid', 'investments.investment_id=sid.investment_id')
            ->join('investment_status', 'investment_status.investment_status_id=(select '.$this->db->dbprefix('investment_status').'.investment_status_id from '.$this->db->dbprefix('investment_status').' where  '.$this->db->dbprefix('investment_status').'.investment_detailed_id=sid.investment_detailed_id order by  '.$this->db->dbprefix('investment_status').'.investment_status_id Desc limit 1)', 'inner')
            ->join('project_status', 'investment_status.project_status_id=project_status.project_status_id')
            ->where('sid.company_type_id', 1)
            ->order_by('investments.investment_id', 'desc')
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage to using Query Builder (QB) unless you need parts of the query to be written differently due to some condition. QB is also useful if you want user inputs to be automatically escaped. Otherwise, you simply run a whole lot of extra code that leads to the exact same SQL statement string you already have.

In your case, the sub-select will make the conversion even more difficult to accomplish and add a lot of extra code to be executed.

My advice is to keep it simple and use `db->query()`, e.g.

```
$sql = "Select siv.company_name, siv.full_name, si.permit_number, si.project_name
    , sid.investment_detailed_id, sis.project_status_id, sps.project_status_name 
    From sma_investors siv 
        Join sma_investments si On siv.investor_id = si.investment_id 
        Join sma_investment_details sid On si.investment_id = sid.investment_id 
        Inner Join sma_investment_status sis On sis.investment_status_id = (
            Select investment_status_id From sma_investment_status s 
            Where s.investment_detailed_id = sid.investment_detailed_id 
            Order BY investment_status_id DESC LIMIT 1) 
        Join sma_project_status sps On sis.project_status_id = sps.project_status_id";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if(! $query)  // might be false if query fails
{
    return null;
}

return $query->row();  // one row of data
```

Comment: i do agree with your advice and i comeup with my own solution pal